# Query multiple Postgres DBs with the same schema

Tags: postgresql

To my knowledge, cross-DB querying is limited in Postgres. So I wonder if there is a way to do the following.

Lets say I have 3 Postgres DBs (A, B and C) with each having the same schema, but different data. They each have a users table. I want to query the count of users in each, grouped by DB.

Like such:

| DB | User Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 90 |
| B | 12 |
| C | 59 |

Not necessarily looking for a solution within Postgres. An external tool will also suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another database. In that database, install postgres_fdw and create foreign servers that point to each of your original databases. Create a foreign table for each of your user tables, and create a view that is a `UNION ALL` of all these foreign tables. Then you can query that view, and from PostgreSQL v14 on, PostgreSQL should be able to query the foreign tables in parallel.

Don't forget to `ANALYZE` your foreign tables before using them.